# Fetch Location Column Corresponding to MIN(Column) and MAX(Column)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
 Select City, Name, MarkDate,Location MIN(InTime) as InTime
 ,MAX(OutTime)as OutTime,SUM(Distance)  as Distance,SUM(Duration) as
 Duration from tblAttendanceTracker JOIN tblEmployee ON
 tblAttendanceTracker.EId= tblEmployee.EId Group By MarkDate,City ,Name
 Order By MarkDate ,City,Name asc
```

How can i Fetch the `Location` Column Corresponding to `MIN(InTime)` and Location Corresponding to `MAX(OuTTime)` .since Location is a single column

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve] for suggestions on how to present your request.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the SQL you provided wouldn't work at all and give error. I got your question as you want to find locations per employee and city based on entry and exit datetimes:

```
WITH summary
AS (SELECT Eid,
           City,
           MarkDate,
           MIN(InTime) AS InTime,
           MAX(OutTime) AS OutTime,
           SUM(Distance) AS Distance,
           SUM(Duration) AS Duration
    FROM tblAttendanceTracker
    GROUP BY Eid,
             MarkDate,
             City)
SELECT s.City,
       e.Name,
       s.MarkDate,
       t.Location,
       s.InTime,
       s.OutTime,
       s.Distance,
       s.Duration
FROM summary s
    INNER JOIN tblAttendanceTracker t
        ON s.Eid = t.Eid
           AND s.City = t.City
           AND s.Markdate = t.Markdate
           AND
           (
               s.InTime = t.InTime
               OR s.OutTime = t.OutTime
           )
    INNER JOIN tblEmployee e
        ON s.EId = e.EId
ORDER BY s.MarkDate,
         s.City,
         e.Name ASC;
```